# Can you add validation for swimlanes in TFS 2018?

Tags: tfs

I have a "Blocked" swimlane that I would like to add validation to. Specifically, I'd like to make a field required to be filled in when a backlog item is moved into this swimlane. Is this possible in TFS 2018? I've looked in the "TFS Process Template Editor" extension but I can't see how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Blocked shouldn't be a swimlane. It should be either a state, a tag, or a field. Work items should not change between swimlanes during their lifecycle.

Comment: Is there any reason for that specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, I prefer to do it with `exportwitd` and `importwitd`.

1. Export the work item XML with `exportwitd`.
2. Add a transition with your `Blocked` state and make a field required.

   ```
   <TRANSITION from="In Progress" to="Blocked">
     <REASONS> 
       <DEFAULTREASON value="Fixed"/>
     </REASONS> 
     <FIELDS>
       <FIELD refname="MyCorp.SomeField" >
         <REQUIRED />
       </FIELD>
     </FIELDS>
   </TRANSITION>`
   ```
3. Import the XML again to TFS with `importwitd`.

Now when a user moves the work item from "In Progress" to "Blocked" the field "MyCorp.SomeField" will be required.

You can find good documenation regarding above [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=tfs-2018), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/transition-xml-element?toc=/azure/devops/reference/toc.json&bc=/azure/devops/reference/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=vsts) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?view=tfs-2018).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't work for swimlanes, only columns. Do you know if it's possible to add a transition rule for Swimlanes?

Comment: You're right, I thought you meant State and not Swimlane. can you add "Blocked" to the states?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. I tried adding a state that looks like this:<STATE value="Blocked"> <FIELDS> <FIELD refname="COMPANY.BlockedReason"> <REQUIRED /> </FIELD> </FIELDS> </STATE>
But no validation is happening.
I think there's no connection between swimlanes and state.